# Creating an index for UITableView based on values inside NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am having trouble creating an index from an `NSArray` containing many `NSDictionaries`, where I want to index the values based only on the `username` key in the dictionary. As illustration, each Dictionary looks something like this:

```
{
     username => "daspianist", //<- Only want to use this value to create index
     objectId => "hjd72h3jd",
     createdAt => "30-1-2014",
     updatedAt => "30-1-2014"
}
```

At the moment I have simplified the issue so that I am indexing an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`, and what I do is the following:

```
//Note that `stringArray` is passed to this method
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (char firstChar = 'a'; firstChar <= 'z'; firstChar++)
    {
        NSString *firstCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", firstChar];
        NSArray *content = [stringArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@", firstCharacter]];
        NSMutableArray *mutableContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:content];

        if ([mutableContent count] > 0)
        {
            NSString *key = [firstCharacter uppercaseString];
            [dict setObject:mutableContent forKey:key];
            NSLog(@"%@: %u", key, [mutableContent count]);
        }
    }
```

I am struggling to convert what I have been doing for NSStrings to be inside the values for the `username` key in my NSDictionaries, and would appreciate whatever guidance.  Thanks!

**Update**

To clarify, the resultant Dictionary that I am interested in would look something like this

```
{
    "a" => {
             username => "aardvark",
             otherKeys => "otherValues"
           },
           {
             username => "applepicking",
             otherKeys => "otherValues"
           }
    "d" => {
             username => "daspianist",
             otherKeys => "otherValues"
           }
      ....
}
```

**Update 2**

The solution typed out based in `Wain`'s answer, for ease of use:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (char firstChar = 'a'; firstChar <= 'z'; firstChar++)
    {
        NSString *firstCharacter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", firstChar];
        NSArray *content = [userNamesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@", firstCharacter]];
        NSMutableArray *mutableContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:content];
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username IN %@", content];

        if ([mutableContent count] > 0)
        {
            NSString *key = [firstCharacter uppercaseString];
            NSArray *values = [originalDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
            [dict setObject:values forKey:key];
            NSLog(@"%@: %lu", key, (unsigned long)[mutableContent count]);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"The dictionary is %@", dict);
```

Comment: So the end result you want is a dictionary. Keys are the single character strings, values are arrays of dictionaries (user names matching the single char key)?

Comment: @Wain Yes, this is correct. For example, the resultant dictionary would have the `key` being "A", and values are the `NSDictionaries` that have `username` begin with "A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `content` is the array of `username`s which match the current key. The goal is to find all of the dictionaries which contain a `username` in that array. This is the job for a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username IN %@", content];
```

now you can do:

```
NSArray *values = [dictArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
[dict setObject:values forKey:key];
```

Comment: Thanks! A great answer using `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the following function:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSMutableArray *charactersForSort = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *item in array)
    {
        NSString *username = [item objectForKey:@"username"]
        if (![charactersForSort containsObject:[username substringToIndex:1]])
        {
            [charactersForSort addObject:[username substringToIndex:1]];
        }
    }

    return charactersForSort;
}
```

Here *array* is a **NSArray** of dictionaries, which you've mentioned in your question.